# PHPMailer back to back emails fail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to create an automatic email responder using PHPMailer, which automatically sends download codes to customers after purchasing through PayPal. Here is the simple code I am working with:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';                 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                   
    $mail->Username = 'orders@example.com';                     
    $mail->Password = 'ExamplePassword1234';                          
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;           
    $mail->Port = 465;


    $mail -> setFrom('orders@example.com', "Orders");
    $mail -> addAddress('johndoe@example.com', "John Doe");
    $mail -> isHTML(true);
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
    $mail -> Subject = "Order Details " . date("Y/m/d h:i:s a") . " CET";
    $mail -> Body = "Here some body text.";
    $mail -> send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

This seems to work just fine, as a one-off. The email arrives in my inbox. But I can't seem to "place" back-to-back orders, i.e. I can't run this script back-to-back and receive back-to-back emails. There must be a required waiting time? Email provider is same as domain provider. Do gmail and outlook implement something that fish out similar emails that arrive near to each other? This is a real drag, I have about 50% success rate while testing and can't tell if I need to do something different. It is not totally uncommon for customers to make multiple purchases in a short time-frame, or for two different customers to make a purchase almost at the same time...Seems fairly unreliable. Debugging logs are identical between when the email arrives and when it doesn't (i.e. SMTP is authenticated, etc. etc. and "Message has been sent").

Server Debug looks like (obviously not sending from "example.com", the credentials I am using are correct):

```
2021-08-16 13:38:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 ESMTP Mon, 16 Aug 2021 09:38:37 -0400: UCE strictly prohibited
2021-08-16 13:38:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.example.com
2021-08-16 13:38:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-walauthsmtp55.yourhostingaccount.com Hello www.example.com [65.254.225.176]250-SIZE 34603008250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPE_CONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-CHUNKING250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2021-08-16 13:38:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-08-16 13:38:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2021-08-16 13:38:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-08-16 13:38:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2021-08-16 13:38:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-08-16 13:38:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2021-08-16 13:38:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<orders@example.com>
2021-08-16 13:38:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2021-08-16 13:38:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<nicholson.thomas@outlook.com>
2021-08-16 13:38:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2021-08-16 13:38:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2021 15:38:37 +0200
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: buyer@example.com
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Orders <orders@example.com>
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Order Details 2021/08/16 03:38:37 pm CET
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <iDN7zl9kx3w84XfuDgKcyJSwMlVJbzxCaxm81E7Qw6E@www.example.com>
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.4.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: A second test before moving back.
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2021-08-16 13:38:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1mFcp4-0004qw-QH
2021-08-16 13:38:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-08-16 13:38:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 walauthsmtp55.yourhostingaccount.com closing connection
Message has been sent
```

**UPDATE**: some comparison testing was interesting, I was able to send 7 back to back emails to Gmail, but still haven't been able to repeat an email to Outlook...

Comment: Is there any error thrown? What's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I've always had troubble with emails ending up in spam folders.
You can check the spam score through this tool: https://www.mail-tester.com/, this will give you some tips what to do about your email reputation.

You can also use a tool like Sendgrid or Mailgun, these emails almost never end up in your spam folder.

Comment: You've enabled verbose debugging but have not included the output generated. Has the SMTP server accepted the message?

Comment: Updated with an example debug above!

Comment: I hope you're not really sending from "example.com"? If you edit debug info then please state so.

Comment: Yes, I am not sending from example.com

Comment: Spam score is 9.8/10 hmm...

Comment: That's a good spam score on mail-tester.com my mails get something similar.

Comment: Really strange, especially discrepancy between Outlook and Gmail, I always get through to Gmail but now hardly ever to Outlook.

Comment: Sending mail has become more and more difficult. I stopped spending time on it and resorted to an external service. In my case it is postmarkapp.com but there are many alternatives.

Comment: This does not show "back to back" emails, they're just individual messages. You can send multiple messages within a single SMTP session using keepalive. See [the PHPMailer mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for how to use that. Sending in batches like this will mean your connection count stays low (because connections <= messages), though you will need to keep an eye on your message rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn PHPMailer debugging on, in order to read the SMTP conversation with the server. The very last commands exchanged will contain something like (for GMail)

```
250 2.0.0 OK  1629104921 f5sm3477300ekj.45 - gsmtp
```

If you get *that* - "f5sm..." is the message-ID - then the thing is out of your hands, and you're probably being hit by a spam filter somewhere. Use some online checker to verify your spam score, modify the email accordingly (keywords, format and structure), and add SPF and DKIM certification as needed.